# Adding contact URL link to certain products in listing

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-list

Is it possible to add a "contact page" link to the product listing, but not in the description but in the area where the 'Add to basket/cart' link is, and  only for certain products via perhaps an attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some customization:

- First **create an attribute**, which defines for which products you
  want to show the contacts link. The attribute setting **Use in product listing** should be "yes".
- Now, change ***list.phtml*** which is located at `app/design/frontend/Your_Package/Your_Theme/template/catalog/product/`

  Add code like this to replace the add to cart button (example for rwd theme):

  ```
  <?php if(!$_product->canConfigure() && $_product->isSaleable()):
  <?php 

  /* I added the condition here:  */

  <?php   if($_product->getMyFlag()=='Your_Condition'): ?>

          <a title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Please Contact'))?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Please Contact') ?></a>

  <?php else :?>

          <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>

  <?php endif ?>
  ```